# disabled dropdown has value reset

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I have a dropdown in an edit form that is disabled via jquery/javascript. When I go in and edit an item/record, save it, and reopen it, the selected value in the dropdown gets reset to its default value. When I remove the javascript that is disabling the control, the values don't get reset. The drop down only has two values; open and closed. he default is open. Here is the javascript:

```
$(function() {
        $("select[title$='Procurement Stage']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The field has to be enabled prior to submission, typically via the [PreSaveAction](http://wael-abbas.blogspot.com/2009/02/sharepoint-presaveaction.html) function.

Marc has it demonstrated [here](http://sympmarc.com/2010/10/08/using-jquery-to-prefill-and-disable-required-column-in-a-sharepoint-form/), I swapped in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("select[title$='Procurement Stage']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    });

    function PreSaveAction() {
        $("select[title$='Procurement Stage']").attr('disabled', ''); 
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Got it. I also found this: http://www.jbmurphy.com/2010/06/01/how-to-make-a-field-in-a-sharepoint-edit-form-readonly/ I guess disabled controls don't get thier values posted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below line in my `PreSaveAction()` but still the drop-down doesn't get enabled.

```
$("select[title$='Status']").attr('disabled', '');
```

But the below line is making the status disable properly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("select[title$='Status']").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended up doing. I wrote my custom function that converts value of select element to text. No issues with posting back to the server this way.

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
       var el= $("select[title$='Status']");
       ConvertToText(el);
 });

function ConvertToText(element)
 {
    var txtHTML = element.val();
    var tdColumn = element.closest('td');
    var tdColumnHTML = $(tdColumn).html();
    $(tdColumn).html("<div style='display:none'>'" + tdColumnHTML +  "'</div>");
    $(tdColumn).append(txtHTML);
 }
```